# How to set indent and formatting behavior for each language in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, format, indentation, auto-indent

Is there a way to make vscode format python files using 4 spaces while formatting files from other languages such JS, Typescript and HTML using 2 spaces only?

It`s pretty annoying to have to indent manually every time.

All of this trying is setting up a mess on my settings and still, I can`t make it work as I want.

This is what my settings.json looks like for the moment

```
  {
    "python.jediEnabled": false,
    "miramac.node.terminalMode": false,
    "python.pythonPath": "/usr/local/bin/python3",
    
    

    "workbench.colorTheme": "Dracula",

    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",

    "workbench.editor.labelFormat": "short",
    

    "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 12,
    "editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code", 
    "editor.lineHeight": 19,
    "editor.fontLigatures":true,
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",

    "editor.renderLineHighlight": "gutter",
    "editor.detectIndentation": true,
    "editor.insertSpaces": false,
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.autoIndent": "full",
    "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
    "eslint.debug": true,
    "eslint.format.enable": true,
    "eslint.options": {
    
    },
    "python.languageServer": "Microsoft",

    "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,

    "[html]": {

    "editor.tabSize": 2,
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll": true,
        },

    },
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "prettier.tabWidth": 2,

    
    "[javascript]":{
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.fixAll": true,
        }
    },
    "[javascriptreact]":{
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.fixAll": true,
        }
    },
    "[typescript]":{
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.fixAll": true,
        },
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "rvest.vs-code-prettier-eslint"
    },
    "[typescriptreact]":{
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.fixAll": true,
        },
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "rvest.vs-code-prettier-eslint"
    },


    "[python]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 4,
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        // "source.fixAll": true,
        },
    },
    
    "extensions.ignoreRecommendations": true,
    

    "explorer.compactFolders": false,
    //perguntar se vc confirma delete e drag and drops
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    //mostra o caminho completo do arquivo 
    "breadcrumbs.enabled": true,
    

    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "never",
    "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "never",
    
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--extension-pkg-whitelist=pygame"
    ],
    
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    
    
    //set zsh theme to my terminal
    //"terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/bash", 
    "terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/bash",
    //"terminal.integrated.cwd": "",
    
    "editor.renderControlCharacters": false,
    "window.zoomLevel": -1,
    "git.path": "/usr/local/git/bin/git",
    "gitlens.views.repositories.files.layout": "list",
    "gitlens.views.compare.files.layout": "tree",
    

    "emmet.syntaxProfiles": {"javascript": "jsx"},
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {"javascript": "javascriptreact"},



    "typescript.tsserver.log": "verbose",
    "javascript.suggest.autoImports": true,

    
    "git.enableCommitSigning": true,
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "git.rebaseWhenSync": true,
    "git.showPushSuccessNotification": true,
    "workbench.sideBar.location": "left",
    "workbench.activityBar.visible": true,
    "terminal.integrated.automationShell.osx": "",
    // "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.python",
    // "editor.tokenColorCustomizationsExperimental": {},
    "workbench.preferredDarkColorTheme": "Dracula",
    "workbench.preferredHighContrastColorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",

    
    
    "material-icon-theme.activeIconPack": "nest",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    
    
    "material-icon-theme.folders.associations": {
        "infra": "app",
        "entities": "class",
        "schemas": "class",
        "typeorm": "database",
        "repositories": "mappings",
        "http": "container",
        "migrations": "tools",
        "modules": "components",
        "implementations": "core",
        "dtos": "typescript",
        "fakes": "mock",
        "coverage_reports": "tools",
    },
    
    "material-icon-theme.files.associations": {
        "ormconfig.json": "database",
        "routes.tsx": "routing",
        "routes.ts": "routing",
        "*.html": "html",

        
    },
    "sqlite.databaseExtensions": [
        "db",
        "db3",
        "sdb",
        "s3db",
        "sqlite",
        "sqlite3",
        "ts"
    ],
  }
```

Would there be anyone who can help in this issue?

Comment: Since you are using the Prettier ESlint as a formatter, make sure you have a prettierrc file and all your language settings in there and ofcourse make sure you have prettier package install via npm. Refer to [Prettier config settings](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html)

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings

Answer (score 0):

I believe option + control + "B" should work

It is also a right click on the document and you should see a "format document" option.

It works for me